# Erro na indexação ao separar Informações da linha

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv('dito_julho.csv')
df.head()

             campanha                           valor
1            Prospect | 5 dias | Com crédito       2
2            Prospect | 5 dias | Com crédito       5
3            Prospect | 5 dias | Com crédito       7
```

Então eu tento criar uma nova coluna com a segunda informação de cada linha da coluna 1, ou seja, quero pegar o "5 Dias"

```
df_teste = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[1])
```

Porém, dá o erro abaixo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-57ecc844181a> in <module>()
----> 1 df_teste = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[1])

c:\users\iuri\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-180-57ecc844181a> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_teste = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Se eu tento fazer com o primeiro campo, que é o Prospect, funciona:

```
df_teste = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[1])
df_teste.head()
>>>>>>>
0    Prospect 
1    Prospect 
2    Prospect 
3    Prospect 
4    Prospect
```

Alguém tem alguma dica do por que eu não consigo pegar essa informação?

Se eu faço um teste, criando algo assim:

```
df_teste = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|"))
df_teste.head()

>>>>>

0     [Prospect ,  5 dias ,  Com crédito]
1    [Prospect ,  20 dias ,  Com crédito]
2    [Prospect ,  40 dias ,  Com crédito]
3    [Prospect ,  75 dias ,  Com crédito]
4     [Prospect ,  5 dias ,  Sem crédito]
```

Fica claro que poderia pegar a informação, 1, os dias, mas isso não ocorre.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você tá tentando usar a coluna certa? No seu exemplo a coluna chama "campanha". E esse `apply` funciona corretamente.

Comment: Em ambos os exemplos você colocou `[1]`, no segundo não seria 0?

Comment: Tem certeza que todas as linhas tem `|`? Basta uma do seu csv nao ter que ira quebrar o codigo.

Comment: Você matou a charada @Begnini algumas linhas não tem isso, consegui resolver listando apenas as que tem o "|"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é usar:

```
def cria_colunas(string_campanha):
    lista = string_campanha.split("|")
    if len(lista) == 0:
        return '', '', ''
    elif len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0], '', ''
    elif len(lista) == 2:
        return lista[0], lista[1], ''
    elif len(lista) == 3:
        return lista[0], lista[1], lista[2]

df['Ação'], df['Prazo'], df['Crédito'] = df['campanha'].apply(cria_colunas)
```

Ou ainda:

```
def cria_acao(string_campanha):
    try:
        return string_campanha.split("|")[0]
    except:
        return ''

def cria_prazo(string_campanha):
    try:
        return string_campanha.split("|")[1]
    except:
        return ''

def cria_credito(string_campanha):
    try:
        return string_campanha.split("|")[2]
    except:
        return ''

df['Ação'] = df['campanha'].apply(cria_acao)
df['Prazo'] = df['campanha'].apply(cria_prazo)
df['Crédito'] = df['campanha'].apply(cria_credito)
```

Isso resolve o problema, mas não acho que seja o melhor jeito.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo! Me ajudou bastante por aqui!

Answer (score 0):

agradeço os comentários acima para me ajudar a resolver o problema, mas identifiquei aqui o que está acontencedo e agora tem outro erro que preciso resolver.

Os dados estão assim na verdade:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_csv('dito_julho.csv')
df.head()

             campanha                           valor
1            Prospect | 5 dias | Com crédito       2
2            Prospect | 5 Dias                     5
3            Prospect                              2
```

O que eu queria fazer é criar uma nova coluna de acordo com cada variavel da linha dividido por "|"

O que fiz até agora foi, separar as linhas que possuem "|"

Depois eu fiz a regra de separar e pegar os dados:

```
df['Ação'] = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[0])
df['Prazo'] = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[1])
df['Credito'] = df['Segmento'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[2])
```

Ai deu o erro de indexação, por que tem linha com 2 campos e tem linha com 3, eu queria saber como posso criar uma função para identificar se caso tenha 3 pegar dos 3 e caso tenha 2 pegar dos dois apenas, pulando o erro de indexação.

Alguém pra ajudar quem tá começando em python aqui haha

Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @Begnini é o que você falou mesmo, os dados estão da forma que mostrei acima, se tiver uma luz pra ajudar agradeço muito! Obrigado!